# Find all real values of $\lambda$ such that $b$ is a linear combination of $a_1, a_2, a_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $a_1 = (3,2,5), a_2 = (2, 4, 7), a_3 = (5,6,\lambda)$.
>   Find all real values of $\lambda$ such that $b = (1,3,5)$ is a linear combination of $a_1, a_2, a_3$.

**I'd be glad if you could criticize my work:**

If $b$ is a linear combination of $a_i$, then we're actually asking when does $Ax = b$ has a solution. The correspond matrix is:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   3 & 2 & 5 & 1  \\
   2 & 4 & 6 & 3  \\
   5 & 7 & \lambda  & 5  \\
\end{array}} \right)$$

Calculating the determinant of $A$ and comparing to zero, we get $\lambda = 12$.
Therefore, in the case where $\lambda \ne 12$, we've a solution and hence, $b$ is indeed a linear combination of $a_i$.

Now, for my understanding, for the case where $\lambda = 12$ there two possibilities: infinite solutions or no solution.
In our case, it is easy to see there's no solution.

**Questions:**

1. Is my proof right/rigorous?
2. For the case of $\lambda = 12$,if we'd got infinite solutions, in this case would $b$ be a linear combination?

Thanks

Comment: How do you calculate the determinant of a non-square matrix?

Comment: Your approach/method is wrong. You can't take the determinant of a non-square matrix. You should transpose $A$ and rowreduce it. Since you want $b$ to be dependent on the other vectors, you want the last row to consist of zeros only. Solve those equations to find $\lambda$.

Comment: Guys, please notice that the last row is $b$, while $A$ is a matrix with the order of $3 \times 3$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It seemed as though you were defining $A$ to be the augmented matrix.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to write it properly, so I just wrote $b$ as the right-most column of $A$.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why you put the augmented matrix there in the first place, since you never actually used solution by row-reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your justification for $\lambda \neq 12$ is valid. Whether the rest of your work is correct depends on what you mean when you say "*it's easy to see [that when $\lambda = 12$], there's no solution*".  How did you verify that this is the case?

And yes, if we got infinitely many solutions for $\lambda = 12$, we'd be able to say that $b$ is a linear combination.

Comment: Applied $\lambda = 12$ and reduced the matrix. Got $0=b_i$ where $b_i \ne 0$. Thanks for your help!